# bash - get directory a script is in when run from a different directory

Tags: bash

If I'm in `/home/whatever` and I run, say, `$ bash /home/folder/subfolder/script1.sh`, how can I get **/home/folder/subfolder** into a variable? `$0` or `$(readlink -f $0)` give me the whole path and filename, i.e. **/home/folder/subfolder/script1.sh**, which isn't what I'm after. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use basename after getting the script name

```
dirname /home/folder/subfolder/script1.sh
```

outputs

```
/home/folder/subfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

p=$(dirname $0)
echo $p
```